# MATLAB error message on startup

Tags: matlab

MATLAB R2014b was working just fine on my machine running 64b Ubuntu 14.04 until this morning. Starting today, whenever I start-up MATLAB, I see the following error messages:

```
Caught "std::exception" Exception message is:
FatalException(unknown)
MATLAB:dispatcher:loadLibrary Can't load '/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014b/bin/glnxa64/libmwmm_rmidd_mi.so': dlopen: cannot load any more object with static TLS

*** MATLAB has encountered a Linux operating system bug; this bug will eventually cause MATLAB to crash. Do not repeat the command which produced this error, as doing so might cause an immediate crash. Save your work and restart MATLAB now..
Caught "std::exception" Exception message is:
FatalException(unknown)
MATLAB:dispatcher:loadLibrary Can't reload '/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014b/bin/glnxa64/libmwmm_rmidd_mi.so'.
Caught "std::exception" Exception message is:
FatalException(unknown)
MATLAB:dispatcher:loadLibrary Can't reload '/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014b/bin/glnxa64/libmwmm_rmidd_mi.so'.
```

Even with these errors, some things still work just fine. But trying to plot anything, or view any figures, causes an error and MATLAB crashes. For example:

```
>> plot([1 2 ],[2,3])
MATLAB:dispatcher:loadLibrary Can't load '/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014b/bin/glnxa64/libmwosgserver.so': dlopen: cannot load any more object with static TLS

*** MATLAB has encountered a Linux operating system bug; this bug will eventually cause MATLAB to crash. Do not repeat the command which produced this error, as doing so might cause an immediate crash. Save your work and restart MATLAB now..
```

I've uninstalled and reinstalled MATLAB, and still this problem persists.

What could be causing this problem? How can I fix it? Why would it arise all of a sudden, after MATLB has worked just fine for so long?

Comment: Try looking at the post I marked as duplicate.  This is not a new problem and it seems to be a bug that plagues a lot of Linux users.  One of the most prominent suggestions is to modify your `startup.m` file and place `ones(10)*ones(10)` as a statement in the file.... I don't know why that even works, but it does.  Good luck!

Comment: What black magic is this! Adding `ones(10)*ones(10)` solved my problem.  Thanks.

Comment: Huh! Did it? Unbelievable! I honestly don't know why it works, but it seems to work for a lot of people using Linux.... Black magic indeed. Glad it helped!